# Can webpack bundle css/scss/less without duplicating required files?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Let's say I have the following 2 components, requiring the same utility css file directly.

Component one:

```
import component1Css from '/path/to/component1.scss'
import someOtherUtilityCss from './path/to/some-other-css.scss'
...
export default Component1;
```

Component two:

```
import component2Css from './path/to/component2.scss'
import someOtherUtilityCss from './path/to/some-other-css.scss'
...
export default Component2;
```

Then I am including them in my app:

Main App:

```
import someLayoutCss from './path/to/some-layout.css';
import Component1 from './path/to/component1'
import Component2 from './path/to/component2'

...

export default App;
```

I would like the bundle system to know to only import `some-other-css.scss` only once.

Is the style-loader + css-loader doing this already out of the box?

Furthermore,

How are the internal css imports handled?

If I have cssFile1 and cssFile2 imported in javascript via import statements:

```
import cssFile1 from 'path/to/file1.scss'
import cssFile2 from 'path/to/file2.scss'
```

And both cssFile1 and cssFile2 internally import cssFile3, will the content of cssFile3 appear duplicated in both the file1.css and file2.css? Or will the sass-loader work this out and include cssFile3 only once?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says:

> **Deduplication**
>
> If you use some libraries with cool dependency trees, it may occur
> that some files are identical. Webpack can find these files and
> deduplicate them. This prevents the inclusion of duplicate code into
> your bundle and instead applies a copy of the function at runtime.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/optimization.html#deduplication

I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: That's cool! So if I include the same css file twice from javascript it will work.

Is pre-compilation happening before module optimisation? I guess that's a better way of asking the question. Are css files processed THEN included in the module system, or are they processed first? If they get processed first, you end up with duplicate code because both cssFile1 and cssFile2 include cssFile3 internally.

Comment: This is so counter-intuitive to me. Does this mean that webpack is duplicating both CSS and JS code if different components import the same files? Wouldn't it be smart enough to see that it already imported a component, meaning it doesn't need to import it again?

The whole idea of injecting multiple identical `<style>` tags in the `<head>` seems nutty to me. Why not detect two identical imports and just inject it once so we don't need to dedupe after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

I think sass-loader will remove duplicate.
If css is not in project, it will duplicate.
And you can use webpack config resolveLoader to remove duplicate.